# yum install error docker

Tags: docker, centos

```
CentOS version:  lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

My repo looks like this

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo 
[dockerrepo]
name=Docker Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/$releasever/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
```

I have some old version of docker and when I try to install it, I get an error. When I try the skip option, even after that the docker service does not even exist on my centos `yum install docker-engine` has the following problem

```
Processing Conflict: docker-engine-1.7.1-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts docker-io
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: docker-engine conflicts with docker-io-0.6.2-1.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest"
```

Then `service docker start` does not exist when I try to start it.

How do I do clean of all docker stuff and do this from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker's official release [no longer supports RHEL/Centos 6](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14365). I think that stopped with 1.7.1 and the official release is at 1.10. I would suggest updating to Centos 7 or anything with a 3.10+ kernel to use the latest `docker-engine` as it has improved quite a bit.

If you are stuck with Centos 6.5 then either continue with the the EPEL docker-io package or install [the 1.7.1 rpm](http://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/6/Packages/docker-engine-1.7.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm).

Completely remove the Centos 6 package

```
yum remove docker-io
```

Remove ***all*** docker data (and ***never*** get it back!)

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

Remove the Docker repo config

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo
```

Either install `docker-io` again

```
yum install docker-io
```

Or install the [docker-engine-1.7.1 rpm](http://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/6/Packages/docker-engine-1.7.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm)

```
yum install http://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/6/Packages/docker-engine-1.7.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Start it and docker

```
service docker start
docker run hello-world
```